# Java - get caller locals

Tags: java, reflection

So, this is my problem: I'm making a plugin for another Java application. In my plugin I have this:

```
public class FooExtended extends Foo
{
    @Override
    public int doSomeWork(int useful, boolean notSoMuch)
    {
        // vital parameter missing...
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that in the `doSomeWork()`, I need another parameter, `vital`. But this parameter is not passed to me, and `FooExtended` is a singleton and `doSomeWork()` is called over and over again for different values of `vital`. But, this parameter is passed to a method two calls "above" `doSomeWork()`, passed to some other methods, but not to me.

Is there a way to get locals of the callers? And also, that is the only call of doSomeWork(), so the line two callers above is unique (no need to worry about reflection not found issues)

Comment: Hows vital defined in your two class upper and is that the same class always going to route the call through stack?

Comment: vital is an int, and it's passed to the method two calls above. doSomeWork() is called ONLY from NotMyClass.makeItWork() which is called ONLY from SomeThirdClass.IHaveVitalAsParam()